# I am overriding magento2 favicon through Magento_Theme web , Firefox sees it but nor Google Chrome

Tags: xml, magento2, favicon, rel

I am adding my own favicon to a custom theme which I develop to Magento 2

I cleaned the caches using

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

and

```
./bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

added

> /Magento_Theme/web/favicon-32x32.png

and the correct code in

> /Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

as shown [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/favicon.html)

when I browse website using Firefox it shows the favicon
but Firefox never showed it

in the DevTools I see there are 3 of the favicons:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://test.me/pub/static/version1573121444/frontend/P/theme-h/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico">

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://test.me/pub/static/version1573121444/frontend/P/theme-h/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico">
```

and also my new favicon-32x32.png

```
<link rel="icon" sizes="32x32" href="http://test.me/pub/static/version1573121444/frontend/P/theme-h/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon-32x32.png">
```

Now why there are 3 of them , and what is that

> rel="shortcut icon"

Comment: did you try clearing the browser cache?

Comment: Yes I did everything to clean but still unable to show the new favicon with Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing the favicon with .ico and .png but only .ico worked in my case. It is also mentioned in dev docs that **Not all browsers support all these formats**.

[image]

Here are the steps which I followed

Step 1:- Create app/design/<Vendor_folder>//Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <link src="Magento_Theme::favicon.ico" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" />
</head>
```

Step 2: Create Magento_Theme/web directory and add you favicon to it.

Result:

[image: Output]